# Help solving $a2^n+b3^n+c4^n=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> If $a,b,c \in \Bbb R$ what are $a,b,c$ such that for every natural $n$, $a2^n+b3^n+c4^n=0$ ?

The rank of the coefficient matrix clearly cannot be more than $1$ so I tried writing $a=\frac{-b3^n-c4^n}{2^n}$.

The answer is $a=b=c=0$ but I do not understand why. Shouldn't the number of solutions be infinite?

Comment: There are infinitely many choices of $a,\,b,\,c$ for a given $n$, but only one choice works for them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking successively $n = 0$, $n = 1$ and $n = 2$ gives you the system $a + b + c = 0$, $2a + 3b + 4c = 0$ and $4a + 9b + 16c=0$, whose unique solution is $a = b = c = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a=-b(3/2)^n-c2^n$ for all $n$,$$-b(3/2)^n-c2^n=-(3b/2)(3/2)^n-2c2^n\implies c=-(b/2)(3/4)^n.$$Taking any two values of $n$ gives simultaneous equations requiring $b=c=0$. Since $a2^n=0$ for all $n$, $a=0$.